# Setting a delay between actions in Swing (Sorting Algorithm Visualizer)

Tags: java, swing, timer, delay

For the sake of learning I've been trying to build a little visualizer ([like this one](http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/)) that shows how different sorting algorithms work. I'm not overly experienced with Swing, and I'm reading that I should use a Timer, but I can't seem to wrap my head around how to actually use it properly.

```
import javax.swing.Timer;
//  .....
public class sortPanel extends JPanel {
    private ArrayList<Integer> list;
    // .....


    public void selectionSort(int msDelay) {
            // code here that loops through and sorts the ArrayList.
            // I know how to do this part but do not want to start it until I get Timer working.
            Timer timer = new Timer(msDelay, new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                        repaint();
                    }
            });
            timer.start(); 
    }
    // .....
}
```

This is what my GUI looks like:

[image: This is what my GUI looks like]

Each of the four panels is an instance of sortPanel. The red circle is the current index of the array the algorithm is on. The start button (for now) calls the selectionSort method in for the first panel.

I was able to get the Timer to work properly when the command was to simply increase the index, but for a more complex task where I want a delay after every index change as well as array modification, I'm not sure how to make it work.

Any suggestions? I'd also appreciate some general criticism of my coding in terms of practices/conventions.

Full source is available [here](http://pastebin.com/P185XCKK).

Comment: Your sorted data is represented by some type of object, and in that object, couldn't you call repaint at certain key events that occur directly in the sorting algorithm itself and perhaps just call a thread.sleep() there as well? (make sure if you do not to execute your sorting algorithm on the EDT)

Comment: I tried to use sleep but it would simply interrupt it until all the actions were done. How would I go about putting the algorithm on a separate thread?

Comment: See [*Concurrency in Swing*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).